# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause error in VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am converting a VB game to C#. I have the following code in VB:

```
Dim files = (From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(contentManager.RootDirectory & "/" & contentFolder, "*.xnb", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

and the converted C# code:

```
var files = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder, "*.xnb", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

But I get the dreaded "A Query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" error. I am trying to find where to put in the select clause. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add `select file` or use fluent syntax.

Comment: Of course, if you *just* want file, then there's no point using `from file` at all. Just assign to `files` directly from the call to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it after your from clause.

VB:

```
Dim files = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(contentManager.RootDirectory & "/" & contentFolder, "*.xnb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

C#:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder, "*.xnb", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
            select file;
```

Comment: You don't need the select in VB.Net.

Comment: Neat, I was not aware that it would add it implicitly. Thanks, @DavidG

Comment: VB does a lot of things implicitly, very annoying if you ask me!